# Why add port could not get Cookie?

Tags: cookies, web

I am added a cookie key-value paire in firefox using firebug.

```
myid:12345
```

And get cookie from server like this:

```
var ccnid = CookieUtil.GetValue("myid");
Response.Write("myid:"+myid);
Response.End();
```

My website url like this:*http://192.168.1.222:8889*.

When set cookie domain like this:http://192.168.1.222. i browser the url:http://192.168.1.222:8889, the response is:**myid:123456**.

When set cookie domain like this:http://192.168.1.222:8889. i browser the url:http://192.168.1.222:8889, the response is:**myid:**.

Why could this happen?The domain:http://192.168.1.222:8889 could not access http://192.168.1.222:8889?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the port like this:`http://192.168.1.222`so your browser could read it,the cookie is having relationship with domain name,not ip+port.